# Xcode png picture importing and implementation in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using `Xcode` (objective-C) with `UIKit` and `SpriteKit`.
I imported an image (.png or .jpeg) into my xCode project by "adding a file to (project)" and I put the image in my supporting files.
I think I figured out how to create a `UIView` in the `didMoveToView` part of my code in one of my .m files:

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), 100, 100);
UIView* View1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
```

but I'm not sure how to attach an image (the .png or .jpeg [doesn't matter] ) to the `UIView` and display it when the program compiles.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Or, if there is a better way to import a picture to Xcode and use it only during the given .m file could someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: add an imageview and set image (png or jpg ) accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UIImage` when coding for it, and use that control in the view. You can actually set the image in the design window and not even have to code it one bit.

If you're developing for a Mac, use an `NSImage`.

If you want to code for it, use an outlet to refer to it, and use actions if you want a user to be able to perform actions with it.

In order to do this (in the newest Xcode), click the button that looks like a Venn Diagram, so that way both your storyboard and your `.m` file show up. **When you want to make an outlet or action, control-click and drag.** Don't Command-click, don't option-click, it's control-click. Connect the lines and you'll have a pop-up, and it'll make a function/outlet for you.

Best of luck! :)

Comment: I tried that originally but the reason it did not work was because I was command-click dragging and, when I did ctrl-click drag, I kept trying to connect the UIImage in every other .h file besides the GameViewController. Now I just have to figure out how to load different .png files for each .h/.m file. Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you want to switch the image, you want to use this:

`yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]`

Switch "yourImage" to the name of your image and "yourImage.png" to the file name of the Image. If you want to use SpriteKit with that, then it's this:

`yourImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]]

JPEG and PNG both work fine in both instances.